# Mongoid Authentication issue in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, authentication, mongoid

I am creating an application using ruby and mongoid. But when I try to create or find a document in any collection using mongoid, i am getting this error

```
Mongo::Error::OperationFailure (not authorized on employee_production to execute command { find: "devices", filter: { token: null } } (13))
```

I have enabled authentication in /etc/mongod.conf and added username and password to mongoid.yml to authenticate mongodb connection.

```
development: 
  clients:    
    default:
      database: employee     
      hosts:
        - localhost:27017
      options:       
        user: 'grapewine'
        password: '@)90GTWqks*'
        roles:
          - 'dbOwner'
        auth_mech: :scram
        auth_source: admin
        connect: :direct
```

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985762/operationfailure-not-authorized-on-tracking-to-execute-command

Comment: this link can also be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881208/how-to-secure-mongodb-with-username-and-password#answer-42929869